# Alter an existing table with a default value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to alter an existing table called `users` which have a column named `type` and i want that column `type` to have a default field `"new memeber"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new default constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.users
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Users DEFAULT ('new_member') FOR type;
```